# iPhone: Drop required thumbnail images to customize a full fledged image

Tags: iphone, image, drag-and-drop, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an iPhone application, where it should allow user to choose/drag and drop some thumbnail kind of images to customize a bigger image(Isometric image rendering) in one module. For ex: There will be a bigger House image given, and there will be set of different small thumbnail image for "Roofing". User can choose any of the interested roof image and drop it to the bigger house image. The selected roof image will fit proportionally and right portion in the bigger house image and get the customized newly constructed house image to the user. I think, i have seen exactly similar kind of functionality in "Thomas" application in "Puzzle" game, where user can drag and drop trains parts images to customize a fully completed train image.

I am thinking, can this drag and drop to proper portion, be done only using Cocos2D? Could someone throw some lights on it and help me to start. Also, Are there any samples?

Comment: Is it possible that the applications you mentioned had every possible combination? If so then dropping a part would just need to find and display the other image with the new configuration. The other way is using image masks and/or placing image parts at a specific location and in a certain z-order

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I would like to know what is the framework/classes that i have to use to achieve this feature? Dropping images should fit into the right portion of the bigger image in the right coordinates. Cocos2D (OpenGL layer) is the only way that i can develop this (or) core animation/graphics also can be used for this. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Anyone could please advise how to achieve such image rendering?

Comment: are your tile images representing an entire part of the house, or is it some pattern with which you fill up a part of the house?

Comment: title images are just for showing as thumbnail. but when user chooses and apply(drag and drop) it, it will be set in the portion of the house such as roofing portion/railing portion etc. I think, its possible using Cocos2d?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve drag and drop functionality using QuartzCore framework.

Comment: Hi, Its just not drag and drop. I have to drop the images at the right portion, its an isometric. For ex: As i said already, there will be a complete house image. Then there will be tile images for different tiled color roofing, railing etc. like exterior designs When i choose a roof color image and drop it to the existing complete house, it should update only that roofing portion with the new one what i dropped. Likewise, it should accept the parts of house with different designs. Kind of customizing the users house design.